# How to scrape CERTAIN (filtered of sorted) twitter followers using R

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I have a problem in **scraping** filtered followers in twitter using R.
To be specific, i'd like to **scrape** twitter followers

1. who have tweets more than 1,
2. who mentioned certain keywords in their tweets,
3. who retweets certain users(people)'s tweets

among A followers(A just for an example).

Below are packages i used. Spaces are to block my private API keys.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("mkearney/rtweet") 
install.packages("rtweet")
library(rtweet)

api_key <-
api_secret_key <-
access_token <- 
access_token_secret <- 
 

mytoken<-create_token(app = "", api_key,api_secret_key,  access_token, access_token_secret, set_renv = FALSE)
```

Codes I used to **scrape** twitter followers who follow certain twitter users are followed.
(FoxNews is only for the purpose to illustrate an example)

```
FoxNews.followers<-get_followers(user="FoxNews",n=75000)
FoxNews.followers.data<-lookup_users(users=FoxNews.followers$user_id)
df.FoxNews<-data.frame(FoxNews.followers)
```

What i need is the list of filtered followers(conditions 1,2,3 above) among <FoxNews.followers>.
I think I can get them if i put some codes in mine but i'm not sure what to put as well as where to put.
I'd so appreciate any advice.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you're basically looking for conditional subsetting. There are many tutorials on this online, e.g. by Googling for `r conditional subsetting`. Each of your requirements basically boil down to common R problems: [1] conditional subsetting against a number, [2] checking whether substrings are present, [3] checking whether strings are present in a set of strings. You may want to look around with this information to solve all your problems.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish.

Comment: I totally got it thanks : )